# m.request: use URL which contains colons

Tags: mithril.js

I have a m.request call like this:

```
    mCmdName = "cn:cmd:list:deselectAll";
    m.request({
        method : "POST",
        url : "/testing/cmd/" + mCmdName,
        data: data
    });
```

Now m.request calls

```
 xhrOptions.url = parameterizeUrl(xhrOptions.url, xhrOptions.data);
```

and tries to replace all ':[name]' parts with data[name] which results in 'undefined' as data doesn't contain any of the keys. Data is just the data object of the XHR request.

Is there a way to prohibit this default behavior?

Thanks, Stefan

PS: I'm asking here and not in mithril mailing list because I can't post there for incomprehensible reasons. Maybe somebody can give me a hint on this.

Comment: Regarding the PS: The Mithril community on Gitter is quite active. You could also try Google Groups.

Comment: @Arthur I meant Google groups where I have the problems, still working on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried
encodeURIComponent("cn:cmd:list:deselectAll")

which gives you
cn%3Acmd%3Alist%3AdeselectAll

If necessary you can decode on the server.